# In Sqlite get top 2 for each name returned in different columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have this that returns the top most recent 2 dates grouped by Hipaa_Short.  I would like the most recent in one column and the 2nd most recent in another column, for each Hipaa_Short.  It is possible that there are missing dates (so there is only one row for the Hipaa_Short) in that case I want the to show the empty value as well. I am using Sqlite3 so I'm sure some 'fancy' stuff won't work.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Hipaa_Short ORDER BY Meeting_Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM Meetings
    )  
WHERE rn < 3
```

This is what I get, but it is not what I want:

```
 pk_id   Hipaa_Short   Meeting_Date     rn
+-------|-------------|--------------+-----+
|   2   |  LastFirst  | 2020-02-01   |  2  |
|   5   |  LastFirst  | 2020-03-01   |  1  |
|   6   |  JoneBob    | 2020-03-01   |  2  |
|   7   |  JoneBob    | 2020-04-01   |  1  |
|   8   |  JonesTom   | 2020-06-01   |  2  |
|   9   |  JonesTom   | 2020-07-01   |  1  |
|   10  |  NortEdw    | 2020-04-01   |  1  |
+-------|-------------|--------------+-----+
```

Meetings Table:

```
REATE TABLE "Meetings" (
    "id_pk" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Hipaa_Short"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Meeting_Date"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "MTG_Year"  INTEGER,
    "MTG_Month" INTEGER,
    "MTG_Day"   INTEGER,
    "CN_Date"   TEXT,
    "Meeting_Type"  TEXT,
    "Date_Added"    TEXT,
    "Annual"    TEXT,
    "LOCSI_Flag"    TEXT,
    "Hipaa_RID" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id_pk"),
    UNIQUE("Hipaa_Short","Meeting_Date")
)
```

Sample Data:

```
 pk_id   Hipaa_Short   Meeting_Date 
+-------|-------------|--------------+
|   1   |  LastFirst  | 2020-01-01   | 
|   2   |  LastFirst  | 2020-02-01   | 
|   3   |  JoneBob    | 2020-02-01   | 
|   4   |  JonesTom   | 2020-02-01   | 
|   5   |  LastFirst  | 2020-03-01   | 
|   6   |  JoneBob    | 2020-03-01   | 
|   7   |  JoneBob    | 2020-04-01   | 
|   8   |  JonesTom   | 2020-06-01   | 
|   9   |  JonesTom   | 2020-07-01   | 
|   10  |  NortEdw    | 2020-04-01   |  
+-------|-------------|--------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
  Hipaa_Short   Prior Date   Next Date  
+-------------|------------+------------+
|  LastFirst  | 2020-02-01 | 2020-03-01 |
|  JoneBob    | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-01 |
|  JonesTom   | 2020-06-01 | 2020-07-01 |
|  NortEdw    |            | 2020-04-01 |
+-------------|------------|------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation on top of your existing query to pivot the resultset:

```
select 
    hipaa_short,
    max(case when rn = 2 then meeting_date end) prior_date,
    max(case when rn = 1 then meeting_date end) next_date,
from (
    select 
        m.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by hipaa_short order by meeting_date desc) as rn
    from meetings m
) m
where rn <= 2
group by hipaa_short
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter form of GMB's answer for this particular problem is:

```
select hipaa_short, min(meeting_date) as prior_date, max(meeting_date) as next_date
from (select m.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by hipaa_short order by meeting_date desc) as rn
      from meetings m
     ) m
where rn <= 2
group by hipaa_short
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already need to sort the partitions to get just the first one, it's easy (And more efficient) to use the `lead()` window function to get both dates in a single row without additional aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS
  (SELECT Hippa_Short
        , lead(Meeting_Date) OVER w AS "Prior Date"
        , Meeting_Date AS "Next Date"
        , row_number() OVER w AS rn
   FROM meetings
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY Hippa_Short ORDER BY Meeting_Date DESC))
SELECT Hippa_Short, "Prior Date", "Next Date"
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

gives

```
Hippa_Short  Prior Date  Next Date
-----------  ----------  ----------
JoneBob      2020-03-01  2020-04-01
JonesTom     2020-06-01  2020-07-01
LastFirst    2020-02-01  2020-03-01
NortEdw                  2020-04-01
```